# Read two columns of variables from CSV, do something to both of them at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, csv, multiple-columns

I have the following CSV:

```
AD_NAME,PTL_NAME
AdminsG,TEST_1
SVC ACCTSG,TEST_2
SQL AdminsG,TEST_3
```

For simplicity of this ? sake, let's say I'm trying to make a new folder for each row in column 0, and within each folder, a text file based on column 1 in the same row:

```
AdminsG
        ->TEST_1.txt
SVC ACCTSG
        ->TEST_2.txt
SQL AdminsG
        ->TEST_3.txt
```

However

```
f = csv.reader(open('GROUP_NAMES.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
next(f)
col = list(zip(*f))[0]
for row in col:  
    os.makedirs(row)
    col2 = list(zip(*f))[1]
    for row in col2:
        #...code to write txt files...
```

returns with

```
IndexError: list index out of range


f = csv.reader(open('GROUP_NAMES.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
next(f)
col = list(zip(*f))[0]
for row in col:  
    os.makedirs(row)
```

creates the 3 root folders just fine, so I think I'm missing the boat on where to plug in the second column variable in the same iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is that the list has only one index with group of set values as:

```
[('AdminsG', 'SVC ACCTSG', 'SQL AdminsG'), ('TEST_1', 'TEST_2', 'TEST_3')]
```

so when you try to excute this line, it try to find index 1 which doesn't exist.

```
col2 = list(zip(*f))[1]
```

you might want to change this as:

```
f = csv.reader(open('temp.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
next(f)
data = list(zip(*f))
row, col = data[0], data[1]
data = (zip(row, col))
for col1, col2 in data:
     os.mkdirs(os.path.join(col1, col2))
```

There is one more alternative to write the same code:

```
import os
import csv

with open('GROUP_NAMES.csv', 'r') as csvReader:
    csv_obj = csv.reader(csvReader)
    for col1, col2 in csv_obj:
       if col1 == 'AD_NAME' and col2 == 'PTL_NAME':
           continue
       os.mkdirs(os.path.join(col1, col2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over complicating the problem here.

Here is a quick solution that I wrote up:

```
f = csv.reader(open('GROUP_NAMES.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
headers = []
for row in f:
   if not headers:
        headers = row
       continue
    path = os.sep.join(row)
    os.makedirs(path)
```

This solution iterates over all the rows (skipping the header row) making a directory for the first column and inside of that directory making another directory for the second column.

The reason that your solution was not working was that you called `list(zip(*f))` twice. The first execution caused the file handle to be fully iterated over. The second execution resulted in an empty list.

Comment: perhaps I made my demo too simple. Let's say I'm using the second column  of variables to do something entirely different, like, make a text file with the value in col[1] ---same row...or even more complicated, peel potatoes or something.  Your code sample does work/help, FYI. I edited the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Yay for arrays. Not the most "pythonic"... but accomplished what I wanted.

```
try:
    with open('GROUP_NAMES.csv','r') as file:
        f = csv.reader(file, 
                          delimiter = ',', 
                          quotechar = '"')
        next(f)
        row = [row for row in f]
        for i in row:
            os.makedirs(i[0])
            file = open(i[0]+'\\'+i[1]+'.txt', 'w')


except:  

    f.close()  
    raise
```

Comment: You don't need that row array. You can can loop over the remaining  lines of the file directly